# Recreating a sentence from the position of each word in it

Tags: python

I am looking to develop a program that identifies individual words in a sentence and replaces each word with the position of each word in the list.

For example, this sentence:

```
HELLO I NEED SOME HELP IN PYTHON PLEASE CAN YOU HELP ME IN PYTHON
```

This contains 11 different words and I'd like my program to recreate the sentence from the positions of these 11 words in a list:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,11,6,7
```

I'd then like to save this new list in a separate file. So far I have only gotten this:

```
#splitting my string to individual words
my_string = "HELLO I NEED SOME HELP IN PYTHON PLEASE CAN YOU HELP ME IN PYTHON"    
splitted = my_string.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_string = "HELLO I NEED SOME HELP IN PYTHON PLEASE CAN YOU HELP ME IN PYTHON"    
>>> splitted = my_string.split()
>>> order = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 11, 6, 7
>>> new_str = ' '.join(splitted[el] for el in order)
'I NEED SOME HELP IN PYTHON PLEASE CAN YOU HELP IN ME PYTHON PLEASE'
```

**Updated** according to your comment:

You are looking for [**`index()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method.

```
my_string = "HELLO I NEED SOME HELP IN PYTHON PLEASE CAN YOU HELP ME IN PYTHON"    
splitted = my_string.split()
test =  "I NEED SOME HELP IN PYTHON PLEASE CAN YOU HELP IN ME PYTHON PLEASE".split()
print ', '.join(str(splitted.index(el)) for el in test)

>>> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 11, 6, 7
```

** we suppose that there are no repeating words

Comment: I think the numbers should be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 7]`

Comment: @SirParselot tuple or list there is no difference for that case (it is just const)

Comment: No I meant the order of the numbers.

Comment: Hello,thank you for your help. I think I have probably not worded my question very well. I would like a user to be able to input any entence they wanted and the programme to output to the user the position of each word.

Comment: For example if a user's input was "I NEED SOME HELP IN PYTHON PLEASE CAN YOU HELP IN ME PYTHON PLEASE", the program would return "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 11, 6, 7"

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = "HELLO I NEED SOME HELP IN PYTHON PLEASE CAN YOU HELP ME IN PYTHON"    
splitted = my_string.split()
d = {}
l=[]
for i,j in enumerate(splitted):
    if j in d:
        l.append(d[j])
    else:
        d[j]=i
        l.append(i)
print l

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 11, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has really helped me :) :)

Comment: @new.teacher don't forget to upvote then and mark the answer that helped the most

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sentence= "HELLO I NEED SOME HELP IN PYTHON PLEASE CAN YOU HELP ME IN PYTHON"
lst = sentence.split()
lst2= []

for i in lst:
    if i not in lst2:
        lst2.append(i)

inp = inputSentence.split()
output=[]
for i in inp:
    print lst2.index(i)+1,
    output.append(lst2.index(i)+1)
```

The index is evaluated and stored in `lst2`. You just have to pass your input string to `inputSentence` , so that you are able to test this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> my_string = "HELLO I NEED SOME HELP IN PYTHON PLEASE CAN YOU HELP ME IN PYTHON"
>>> splitted = my_string.split()
>>> key_val = {elem : index + 1 for index, elem in enumerate(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(splitted)))}
>>> [key_val[elem] for elem in splitted]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 11, 6, 7]
```

`list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(splitted))` create a list having only unique elements from `splitted`.
`key_val` is dictionary of these unique elements as key and their index as the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
benstring = input ('enter a sentence ')

print('the sentence is', benstring)

ben2string = str.split(benstring)

print('the sentence now looks like this',ben2string)

x=len(ben2string)   
for i in range(0,x):
    if x is
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sentence = input("Enter a sentence!")
s = Sentence.split() #Splits the numbers/words up so you can see them individually.
another = [0]

for count, i in enumerate(s):
    if s.count(i) < 2:
        another.append(max(another) + 1) #adds +1 each time a word is used, showing the position of each word.
    else:
        another.append(s.index(i) +1)

another.remove(0)

print(another) #prints the number that word is in.
```